# Julia: converting any vector of type to vector of real

Tags: vector, types, type-conversion, julia, any

I define the type

```
type mytype
    e1:: Real
    e2:: Real
end
```

I want to have a vector of mytype:

```
Vmtype = Array{mytype}(10)
```

when I ask julia for the 10 e1. I get an error
Vmtype[1:2].e1
ERROR: type Array has no field e1

How can I access the Vector `Vmtype[1:10]`?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to fill in the values of `Vmtype`. What you are doing is creating an "empty" array of type `mytype`.

```
Vmtype = Array{mytype}(10)
e1s = collect(1:10)
e2s = collect(91:100)

for i in 1:10
    Vmtype[i] = mytype(e1s[i], e2s[i])
end
```

then you can access the fields as

```
Vmtype[1].e1
```

Notice that one thing is an object of type `mytype` and another is an array with elements of type `mytype`. See http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#man-parametric-types

EDIT:

To create another array with the e1s of `Vmtype` you can use

```
Ae1 = map(x -> x.e1, Vmtype)
```

Then you can use `Ae1` in `plot((1:10), Ae1)`.

Comment: I wonder if one can somehow overload the `.` operator to make it work with `Array`s.

Comment: Thanks for the correction amrods. However, I still get an error message when I type Vmtype[1:2].e1. Is there any way to access the entire Vector Vmtype[1:10].e1. What I want to do is to run plot((1:10),Vmtype[1:10].e1)?

Comment: The thing is that `Vmtype` does not have any fields; its _elements_ have the `e1` and `e2` fields. What you can do is populate another array with the e1 values of the elements of `Vmtype`, check the edit.